# Time evolution of a system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, time-evolution, parity

I am confused on how they get the evolved state of system. Can someone explain this to me please?

> **Problem:** A quantum system has only two eigenstates, $|1\rangle$, $|2\rangle$, corresponding to the energy eigenvalues $E_1$ and $E_2$. Apart from the energy, the system is also characterized by a physical observable whose operator $P$ acts on the energy eigenstates as follows:
>
> $$P|1\rangle=|2\rangle,\qquad P|2\rangle=|1\rangle$$
>
> $P$ can be regarded as a "parity" operator.
>
> Find the eigenstates and eigenvalues of $P$.

> **Solution:**
>
> Construct the following linear combinations $|1\rangle\pm|2\rangle$. It is then clear that
>
> $$P(|1\rangle\pm|2\rangle)=\pm(|1\rangle\pm|2\rangle)$$
>
> Therefore, the eigenstates of $P$ are
>
> $$|\pm\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(|1\rangle\pm|2\rangle)$$
>
> and the inverse relations as
>
> $$|1\rangle=\frac1{\sqrt2}(|+\rangle+|-\rangle),\qquad|2\rangle=\frac1{\sqrt2}(|+\rangle-|-\rangle)$$
>
> The evolved state of the system is then
>
> $$|\psi(t)\rangle=e^{i\alpha t}(\cos(\omega t)\,|+\rangle+i\sin(\omega t)\,|-\rangle)$$
>
> with
>
> $$\omega=\frac{E_2-E_1}{2\hbar},\qquad\alpha=-\frac{E_2+E_1}{2\hbar}.$$

Comment: Hello! I have converted your screenshot to text using MathJax (LaTeX) math typesetting (for future questions, you can refer to [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/)). Question (b) seemed irrelevant to your question, so I left it out – feel free to add it back in if needed. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Jon, I've voted to close your question for the reason that, in its current form, it doesn't show any effort to work through the problem. You may edit the question to show some of your own work and to identify the specific conceptual issue that isn't clear to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question doesn't specify the initial state of the system but judging by the highlighted line in the solution, it is the $|+\rangle$ state.

You are told that $|1\rangle$ and $|2\rangle$ are energy eigenstates with energies $E_1$ and $E_2$ respectively. An energy eigenstate acquires a phase $e^{-iEt/\hbar}$ under time evolution, which can be seen from the form of the time evolution operator.

So write the state $|+\rangle$ in terms of the energy eigenstates and multiply each by its corresponding phase acquired under time evolution, which gets you: $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(e^{-itE_1/\hbar}|1\rangle + e^{-itE_2/\hbar}|2\rangle )$$
You should then take out a common factor of $e^{i\alpha t}$ which gets you:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}e^{i\alpha t} (e^{i\omega t}|1\rangle + e^{-i\omega t}|2\rangle )$$

You then need to write $|1\rangle$ and $|2\rangle$ once again in terms of $|\pm \rangle$. Expanding the complex exponentials in terms of $\cos{(\omega t)}$ and $\sin{(\omega t)}$ should then get you the desired result.